# Running Google Insights test generates image 404s

Tags: http-status-code-404, pagespeed-insights

Noticed something strange by chance when running a Google Insights speed test on my site. For some reason, it slows down my site almost to a halt and maxes out my server resources. Talking to the host, they noticed that the test generates loads of 404s that are all images. This is very strange since the images are clearly there. They only appear as 404s when running the speed test.

I have done some testing, deactivating every plugin on all of my three sites and it happens on all of them. The only thing they have in common really is that they use the same theme and, of course, that they are running on the same server. The host says it's not on their side though.

I have reached out to the support for the theme, but still want to check with you guys too if this is something you have ever come across and if someone has any experience with this?

I suspect there is something in the code causing this to happen, but I really have no clue. It only seems to happen with Google Insights too, not when I run a test with GTMetrix for example.

Comment: could be a few things, do you want to share your URL in a comment so we can have a look for you.

Comment: Hi Graham, thank you for taking interest in my post. I know this complicates things, but I'd rather not share my URL publicly. Is there any way I can share it with you through a pm?

Comment: if you want to go to my website https://klu.io/contact-us and send a message through the form we can email back and forth if you like.